# Install packages without internet

Tags: package-management

How do I install ubuntu packages from the ubuntu cd. I have ubuntu-desktop 10.04 running and I have to install wvdial package but no internet connection for installing from apt repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since wvdial is on the installation CD, you can enable *System -> Administration -> Software Sources -> Ubuntu Software -> Installable from CD-ROM/DVD -> Cdrom with Ubuntu 10.04* and then install it via Synaptic.

In the long run, though, you should have a way to install software upgrades and packages that aren't included on the CD. For this I recommend using [Keryx](http://keryxproject.org/), which is essentially a relay for your package manager over a USB drive. Updates can be downloaded using an internet-connected computer running Windows, OS X, or Linux.

Comment: Isn't there any option to install from command line as Software Sorces could not add the cd-rom.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing%20packages%20without%20an%20Internet%20connection

Answer (score 1):

See APTonCD

http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/APTonCD

Comment: I think I can't try this as this require internet

Answer (score 1):

Using System -> Administration -> Software Sources (or Settings -> Edit Origins in KPackageKit), go to Other Software tab and click "Add CD-ROM" while the CD is in the drive.  Choose to reload the software sources, and then install as usual.  It'll use the CD as a repository.

Comment: When i click "Add CD-ROM" it prompts to insert cd. The cd is inserted and no problem with the cd drive and the cd is mounted on the desktop automatically. Don't know what's the problem.

Comment: I think it's getting dependency error

Answer (score 0):

It is not dependency error. The apt is not recognizing it.

Try to see where the cdrom mounts, by entering command `mount` in the terminal. It probably mounts on `/media/cdrom` but apt recognizes cdrom in the `/media/apt` directory. so make a symbolic link

`sudo ln -s /media/cdrom /media/apt`. After that you can enter this command,
 `sudo apt-cdrom add`, it will work.